# Is there an easy solution for parsing html in swift to get individual elements into their own variable?

Tags: html, swift, xcode, parsing

I have code which I found online that pulls the HTML off a website and then prints it out. I need to save these into a variable to I can display/ use these in my app.

I am fairly new to this kind of thing and really just need pointers, I don't mind researching! I just need to know what steps I need to be looking into!

```
import UIKit
// run asynchronously in a playground
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// create a url
let url = URL(string:  "https://www.stackoverflow.com")

// create a data task
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("there's a problem")
    }
    print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")

}

//running the task w/ resume
task.resume()
```

This (in Xcode playground) takes the HTML and prints it out using:
`print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")`
Can anyone please help me out getting maybe the `<title>...</title>` element into its own variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing HTML without a third party is not achievable without a `WebView`, **BUT YOU CAN** easily use a webView and run a `getElementsByTagName` with `JS` on it to get anything from the HTML code like this:

1- Define the js code:

```
let js = "document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML"
```

2- Import `WebKit` and load the html into a webView

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    let html = """
    <#the HTML code, can be loaded from anywhere#>
"""

    override func loadView() {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self // Here is the Delegate
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)

        self.view = webView
    }
}
```

3- Take the delegation and implement this method:

```
extension MyViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(js) {(result, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            print(String(describing: result))
        }
    }
}
```

**Note 1**: remember `getElementsByTagName` returns an array and you must pass the index you want the get like `[0]`

**Note 2**: since it use `JavaScriptCore`, it can't be done without webView, and it must be run on mainThread. Only safari can do this off main thread, because it has V8 engine.

**Note 3**: You must wait for delegate to be completed even if you pass the HTML statically

**Note 4**: you can use a third party framework like [SwiftSoap](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) to do this.

Comment: Ok, this is super helpful & ill take a good look through it soon! However, it still seems very clunky... How would you recommend linking my app to some sort of server (preferably free while im still in development) or website so update/ change text within the app itsself? (its a kind of tutorial app)

Comment: Perfect. I add another note.

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you use localhost?

Comment: Because I found it very hard to find a reliable free host... and I couldn't get it working properly... again, id need to pull varchars off the database and display... i could never get this working...

Comment: I personally recommend to have a local server on your machine. You can build one [using Swift too](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1323930-vapor-vs-kitura-choosing-a-server-side-swift-framework)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198756/discussion-between-taylor-styles-and-mojtaba-hosseini).